# Re-order columns on Mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am the beginner and designing the website in the Wordpress using the template.

I have problem with one section. Desktop Column Order (image – text, text - image): [IMAGE] [TEXT] [TEXT] [IMAGE].

I would like to have the following order on the Mobile (image-text): [IMAGE] [TEXT] [IMAGE] [TEXT]

Here is my code:

```html
<div data-label="Top 2" data-id="overlappable--4" data-export-id="overlappable-1" data-category="overlappable" class="overlappable-1 content-section content-section-spacing" data-overlap="true" id="top-2" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"\> \<div class="gridContainer"\> \<div data-type="row" class="row shadow-medium"\> \<div data-type="column" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 flexcol bg-color-white col-md-6"\> \<img decoding="async" class="custom-image" src="http://dionypos.pl/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/Oszczednosc-pieniedzy-1.png" title="Oszczednosc pieniedzy" alt=""\>\</div\> \<div data-type="column" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 flexcol col-padding col-padding-small-xs inverted col-md-6 bg-color-black"\>\<i class="fa icon white fa-dollar large color2"\>\</i\> \<h5 class="inverted"\>OCZCZĘDZAJ PIENIĄDZE! NAWET DO 50% MIESIĘCZNIE!\</h5\> \<p class=""\>Implementacja nic nie będzie Cię kosztować, a rozwiązanie pozwoli&nbsp; zaoszczędzić nawet do 50% miesięcznie.\</p\> \<a class="button inverted color2 outline" href="#" target="\_self" data-cp-link="1" data-icon="" rel="noopener"\>Dowiedz się więcej\</a\> \</div\> \<div data-type="column" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 flexcol col-padding col-padding-small-xs inverted col-md-6 bg-color-black"\>\<a data-cp-link="1" href="#" class="" target="\_self" rel="noopener"\>\<i class="fa icon fa-clock-o large color2"\>\</i\>\</a\> \<h5 class="inverted"\>OSZCZĘDZAJ CZAS!&nbsp;\</h5\> \<p class=""\>Zapewniamy wsparcie przy instalacji do 24 godzin od momentu zakupu oprogramowania. Sam możesz to zrobić w zaledwie kilka minut korzystając z naszego samouczka.\</p\> \<a class="button color2 outline" href="#" target="\_self" data-cp-link="1" data-icon="" rel="noopener"\>Skontaktuj się z nami\</a\> \</div\> \<div data-type="column" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 flexcol bg-color-white col-md-6"\>\<img decoding="async" class="custom-image" src="http://dionypos.pl/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/Oszczednosc-czasu.png" title="Oszczednosc czasu" alt=""\>\</div\> \</div\> \</div\> \</div\>
```

What I need to do in the code/css to get the right result on mobile?

css and html modification but without success

Comment: Do some reading on CSS Grid layout. :-)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Desktop Column Order is displayed: